# How can I display the current datetime in the given format including microseconds in Perl?

Tags: perl, date-formatting

I want Perl to display current date and time in the following format:

```
2010-02-11 13:12:34.87876
```

I wrote this code:

```
use Time::localtime;
my $tm = localtime;
printf("It is now %04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d\n", $tm->year+1900,
    ($tm->mon)+1, $tm->mday, $tm->hour, $tm->min, $tm->sec);
```

and got:

```
2011-11-17 17:22:59
```

I do not know how to get the remaining **.87876** in the output. Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
use DateTime::HiRes qw();
DateTime::HiRes->now(time_zone => 'local')->strftime('%F %T.%5N')
# returns '2011-11-17 17:42:42.21719'
```

- [`DateTime::HiRes`](http://p3rl.org/DateTime%3a%3aHiRes)
- [`strftime` in `DateTime`](http://p3rl.org/DateTime#strftime-Patterns)

Answer (score 8):

Using [`DateTime`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime) and [`Time::HiRes`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/HiRes.html):

```
use DateTime;
use Time::HiRes;

my $dt = DateTime->from_epoch(
    epoch     => Time::HiRes::time,
    time_zone => 'local',
);
print $dt->strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%5N"); # 2011-11-17 21:03:46.74562
```

This is exactly how [`DateTime::HiRes`](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/JHOBLITT/DateTime-HiRes-0.01/lib/DateTime/HiRes.pm) creates `DateTime` objects with sub-second resolution.

Comment: This is incorrect and is limited to microseconds due to using gettimeofday() behind the scenes (and not nanoseconds like DateTime::HiRes).

Comment: @Michael Your comment does not make any sense. If you follow the link I posted back in 2011, you'll see that [`DateTime::HiRes`](https://st.aticpan.org/source/JHOBLITT/DateTime-HiRes-0.01/lib/DateTime/HiRes.pm) still does the same thing as my code. My code just  saves you a dependency.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for `%5N`. See [DateTime::Format](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-Format-Strptime-1.5000/lib/DateTime/Format/Strptime.pm#STRPTIME_PATTERN_TOKENS)